# Check if ID Is Found Another Array in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I wanted to filter out the data. I wanted to check if data on `data1` is found on `data2` and to check if it has errorMessages. Please check my code below. Is there a better way to do it?

**data1**

```
[
    {
        "ids": "0111",  
    },
    {
        "ids": "0222",
    },
    {
         "ids": "0333",
    }
]
```

**data2**

```
[
  {
    "id": "0111",
    "errorMessages": [
      {
        "message": ["sample error message 1"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0333",
    "errorMessages": []
  }
]
```

**Code**

```
const output= data1.filter(
  (element) => element.ids === data2.find((data) => data).id
);

console.log("output", output);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find((data) => data)` doesn't do anything useful - each item in the array is an object, which is truthy, so that'll always return the first element in the array.

If you *did* want to `.find` a matching element in the other array - then a better approach would be to make a Set of the IDs found in the other array first (Set lookup is much quicker - `O(1)` - than `.find`, which is `O(n)`).

You also need to implement the logic to check if the `errorMessages` is empty.

```js
const data1 = [
    {
        "ids": "0111",  
    },
    {
        "ids": "0222",
    },
    {
         "ids": "0333",
    }
]
const data2 = [
  {
    "id": "0111",
    "errorMessages": [
      {
        "message": ["sample error message 1"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "0333",
    "errorMessages": []
  }
]


const ids = new Set(
  data2
    .filter(item => item?.errorMessages.length)
    .map(item => item.id)
);

const output= data1.filter(
  element => ids.has(element.ids)
);
console.log("output", output);
```

Comment: Thank you but 0333 shouldnt be there since its errorMessages is empty

Comment: Sorry but there's a change in data1. It should be ids not id

Comment: OK, then use `.has(element.ids)` instead of `.has(element.id)`

Comment: Thank you. sometimes errorMessages field is there. sometimes its just empty.  Would it still work? ` .filter(item => item.errorMessages.length)`

Comment: If you want the item to be excluded if the property doesn't exist, use optional chaining: `item.errorMessages?.length` which'll evaluate to `undefined` (and exclude the item as a result) without throwing.

Comment: Can you also edit your answer with that? Thank you.

Comment: If we don't want to return undefined so as not to crash the browser. Is this the way to do it?
`.filter((item) => (item.errorMessages|| []).length)`

Comment: You can do that, but optional chaining is the more semantic approach. `item.errorMessages?.length`

Answer (score 0):

Without Set, but use Object as the map.

```js
const IDKeys = {};

data2.forEach(data => {
    if (data.errorMessages.length){
       IDKeys[data.id] = true; // means valid 
    }
})


const filteredArray = data1.filter(data => IDKeys[data.id]);
```

This would be only O(n) since accessing key on object is O(1)